# Regex does not work will tailing quote

Tags: java, regex

I have regex to remove the match the string that MAY start and end with quotes. So I created a regex to do this.

```
String str = "#TEST_ENV_TEST_VAR=\"value\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#TEST_ENV_(.*)=\"?(.*)\"?");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
matcher.find()
String key = matcher.group(2);
```

But when I check the `key` and string is `value"`. It should be `value` right because we have added `?` at the end.

I try using `[]?` regex and also try with `*` but none work.

Comment: omit the ``?`` at the end. The ``(.*)`` is greedy and consumes the ``"``.

Comment: Ohh I see. Then how can I achieve this?

Comment: See [`"#TEST_ENV_([^=]*)=\"?(.*[^\"])\"?"`](https://ideone.com/l1hvl9), but it won't match empty `key`s.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the last `?` because it stops the greediness of `(.*)` and stops at the first `"`

```
#TEST_ENV_(.*)=\"?(.*)\"
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/feNnkg/1)**

---

Otherwise, if the goal is only to match the string between quotes, you could simply use positive lookaheads and lookbehinds

```
(?<=\").*(?=\")
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EprrXy/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

This one will match your stuff correctly:

```
#TEST_ENV_([^=]*)=(\"?)([^\"]*)\2
```

This captures:

- your `#TEST_ENV_` string
- anything not an equal sign, in the first group
- the equal sign itself
- an optional quote, as group #2
- the contents of the quote, defined as "anything not a quote"
- A back-reference to group 2, meaning it requires a bracket if the front has one.

Of course, the data will be in group #1 and group #3, since #2 is used for the brackets.

[Test it yourself](https://regex101.com/r/PioHLd/1).